# C++ Breaking even number into prime factor

Tags: c++

I have created a program in which it can break a given even number into a sum of two primes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int i(int x, int y)
{
    if (x > y)
    {
        if (x % y)
            return i(x, y + 1);
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    else
        return (x > 1);
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please input a positive even number: ";
        cin >> a;

        if (a % 2 == 0 && a >= 1)
        {
            for ( b = a/2; b > 1; b--)
            {
                if ((i(b, 2) && i(a-b, 2)) &&
                    printf("%i + %i\n", b, a-b));
            }
        }
        else if (a % 2 != 0 && a >= 1)
        {
            cout << a << "="<< a << endl;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    while(a >= 4);

    return 0;
}
```

However, I wanna break  the even number into prime factor multiplying prime factor , for example, 12 = 2 * 2 * 3. Any tips for modifying the program? Thanks for your help

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=prime+factorization+c%2B%2B

Comment: The code you are providing has almost nothing in common with your goal. What you are asking is called factorization, and is endlessly revisited. Dig around, and ask something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
// A function to print all prime factors of a given number n
void primeFactors(int n)
{
    // Print the number of 2s that divide n
    while (n%2 == 0){
        printf("%d ", 2);
        n = n/2;
    }

    // n must be odd at this point.  So we can skip one element (Note i = i +2)
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2){
        // While i divides n, print i and divide n
        while (n%i == 0){
            printf("%d ", i);
            n = n/i;
        }
    }

    // This condition is to handle the case when n is a prime number
    // greater than 2
    if (n > 2){
        printf ("%d ", n);
    }
}
```

From http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/

Comment: Ohh thanks. This code seems to be more related to my expectation

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the best one to solve your problem but you can go for it or a limited purpose :-)

```
   int r,q,a,i;
   cout << "Please input a positive even number: ";
   cin >> a;

   if (a % 2 == 0 && a >= 1)
   {
     for (i=2;i<=a;i++)
     {
         r=a%i;
         while (r==0)
         {
           cout<<i<<"*";
           q=q/i;
           r=q%i;    
         }
     }
   else
   {
    cout<<"Number is not even";
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. this program is really inspiring.

Comment: You are welcome :-) and you can favor me by marking it as an answer on the given tick mark  :-P